# How can I insert a delay on every request on a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to test how my client application will behave when the server is far away and the connection is not great. The client is a JavaFX application using Spring's RestTemplate and the server is a RESTful Spring Boot application.

How can I artificially inject a delay on **every** request the server gets?

Comment: Using a servlet filter.

Comment: Use a proxy that can simulate latency, e.g. [toxiproxy](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy).

Comment: Yeah I agree with the proxy idea. Don't want to check in code which does this.

Comment: I'm happy to use code, I don't need to check it in.

Comment: Why don't you use Thread sleep?

Comment: @Zico: yeah, the question is how to do it on every request.

Comment: @Pablo Do you need it for automated or manual tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `HandlerInterceptor` which override `preHandle` and `postHandle` method.

`preHandle` will be invoked **before** request go to Controller.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
```

`postHandle` will be invoked **after** completing Controller's method.

```
 @Override
 public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
```

Any of the method you can use `Thread.sleep()` to delay request/response.

You have to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in which you can attach the `HandlerInterceptor` for servlet

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(MyHandlerInterceptor);
}
```